# Updating a nested array in reducer in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am trying to update a particular index in an array of objects in reducer. The state has an array of objects. isSearch is a property of the object. In the payload of action I am passing the index to be updated and the value. This is my code:

```
case actions.UPDATE:
  return {
    ...state,
    arrObj: {
      ...state.arrObj,
      arrObj[action.payload.index].isSearch : action.payload.isSearch,
    },
  };
```

I get this error `Unexpected token, expected , at arrObj[action.payload.index].` Could someone tell me how can I correct this?

Comment: So what `arrObj[action.payload.index].isSearch : action.payload.isSearch,` is supposed to mean?

Comment: @zerkms I am assigning arrObj[action.payload.index] object a property isSearch

Answer (score 1):

I guess `immutability-helper` package from `npm` will of great help to you in updating the nested redux state

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

.......

case actions.UPDATE:
  return update(state, {
         arrObj: {
             [action.payload.index]: {
                 isSearch: {
                      $set: action.payload.isSearch
                 }
             }
          }
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to update a single value deep within your state, try this:

```js
case actions.UPDATE:
  var newState = { ...state }
  var arrayObj = newState.arrayObj = state.arrayObj.slice()
  var element = arrayObj[action.payload.index] = { ...arrayObj[action.payload.index] }
  element.isSearch = action.payload.isSearch
  return newState
```

Comment: I fixed the browser hanging issue. However the state doesnt seem to change. element isnt being assigned to anything while returning newstate.

Comment: Is there already supposed to be an object at `action.payload.index`? If not, I would need to change the code above.

Comment: There is already an object.   This worked -  
`const newState = { ...state };
      if (action.payload.index) {
        newState.arrObj[action.payload.index].isSearch = action.payload.isSearch;
      }
      return newState;`